# Distinguishing start of digitally signed message digest

Tags: digital-signature, hmac, digest, ecdsa

Since I just created this crude test using the functions from IETF RFC 4634, I don't know for certain whether I've used them correctly for HMAC-SHA-384-192, so I'll start with that code here:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "sha.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        HMACContext hmac;
        const unsigned char *keyarr = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
        int err = hmacReset(&hmac, SHA384, keyarr, 48);
        if (err != shaSuccess) {
                printf("err 1\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        const uint8_t testarray[65] = {'I',' ','a','m',' ','n','o','t',' ','a',' ','c','r','o','o','k','!'};
        const unsigned char *prfkey = "abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789";
        memcpy((void *)testarray + 17, (void *)prfkey, 48);
        const int testlen = 65;
        err = hmacInput(&hmac, testarray, testlen);
        if (err != shaSuccess) {
                printf("err 2\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        uint8_t Message_Digest[USHAMaxHashSize];
        err = hmacResult(&hmac, Message_Digest);
        if (err != shaSuccess) {
                printf("err 3\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 24; i++) printf(" %02X", Message_Digest[i]);
        putchar('\n');
}
```

If I've done everything right (other than selecting good keys) so far, I would ordinarily have a 24-byte (i.e., 192-bit) digest, but if I digitally sign the digest prior to appending it, my experience is that the signature block isn't a predictable length.  I'm sure I could come up with any number of ways to identify the end of the message portion, but I don't want to make this a hack.  What is the accepted way of doing this?  (The signature will use ECDSA.)

I should also mention that this will be a multicast message using UDP inside ESP, since that puts constraints on message economy.  (That's also the main reason for the problem--keeping it binary.  The other is the practice of appending, rather than prefixing it with a byte count in front of it.)

Comment: What do you mean with "digitally sign the digest prior to appending it"? How do you determine the length of the signature block?

Comment: Note that HMAC-SHA-384-192 doesn't make too much sense. SHA-384 is basically SHA-512 with different constants and then taking 384 bits from the output. You are first taking 384 bits from the output only to shorten it further to 192 bits. In other words, you might as well use SHA-256 (faster on 32 bit machines) or SHA-512 (faster on 64 bit machines) instead of SHA-384.

Comment: After further investigation, I see that the problem is with the murky doecumentation of openssl.  When I think I'm signing a digest, I'm actually creating a digest of the digest and signing that, and since there seems to be no support for auth-trunc (HMAC-SHA-384-192), it's apparently not even able to create the correct hash even if I were to hand the job over to it.

Comment: As for why 384 instead of 512, I don't know.  That decision was made by someone else.  However, the spec that mentions it refers in general to IETF RFC 6380.

Comment: Just calculating HMAC-384 and splitting that in half should do the trick... But beware that the verification of the result should be time constant...

Comment: I'm already doing that.  Signing it compatibly and without rehashing an existing hash is the problem.  If openssl provides a stepwise option using ECDSA alone, I have yet to find it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sute what you are trying to do but the hash is an integral part of the signature algorithm for ECDSA. It doesn't use hash-then-encrypt like RSA does (well kind of does anyway). So it is less likely that you can change that. You might be able to set the state of the underlying hash to a pre calculated one maybe. But you are operating even outside my comfort zone right now.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that each signature is different because of the timestamp component.